# Construct a numpy array by repeating a 1 dimensional array sliced at different indices

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (called `base_mortality`) with 1 column and n rows, which is of the following form:

```
    age   |   death_prob   
---------------------------
    60    |   0.005925
    61    |   0.006656
    62    |   0.007474
    63    |   0.008387
    64    |   0.009405
    65    |   0.010539
    66    |   0.0118
    67    |   0.013201
    68    |   0.014756
    69    |   0.016477
```

`age` is the index and `death_prob` is the probability that a person who is a given age will die in the next year. I want to use these death probabilities to project the expected annuity payment that would be paid to an annuitant over the next t years.

Suppose I have 3 annuitants, whose names and ages are contained in a dictionary:

```
policy_holders = {'John' : 65, 'Mike': 67, 'Alan': 71}
```

Then I would want to construct a new dataframe whose index is time (rather than age) which has 3 columns (one for each annuitant) and t rows (one for each time step). Each column should specify the probability of death for each policy holder at that time step. For example:

```
         John      Mike      Alan
0    0.010539  0.013201  0.020486
1    0.011800  0.014756  0.022807
2    0.013201  0.016477  0.025365
3    0.014756  0.018382  0.028179
4    0.016477  0.020486  0.031269
..        ...       ...       ...
96   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
97   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
98   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
99   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
100  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```

At present, my code for doing this is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

base_mortality = pd.read_csv('/Users/joshchapman/PycharmProjects/VectorisedAnnuityModel/venv/assumptions/base_mortality.csv', index_col=['x'])
policy_holders = {'John' : 65, 'Mike': 67, 'Alan': 71}

out = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,101))

for name, age in policy_holders.items():
    out[name] = base_mortality.loc[age:].reset_index()['age']
out = out.fillna(1)
print(out)
```

However, my aim is to remove this loop and achieve this using vector operations (i.e. pandas and/or numpy functions). Any suggestions on how I might improve my code to work in this way would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). It returns the bin in which each event lies. You can even pass the labels directly. This way you can reduce it to a Python loop over the people:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

age_bins = range(59, 70)   # one more than the probabilities
death_prob = [0.005925, 0.006656, 0.007474, 0.008387, 0.009405, 0.010539, 0.0118,
              0.013201, 0.014756, 0.016477]

policy_holders = {'John' : 65, 'Mike': 67, 'Alan': 71}

values = {name: pd.cut(range(age, age + 101), age_bins, labels=death_prob)
          for name, age in policy_holders.items()}

out = pd.DataFrame(values, dtype=np.float64).fillna(1)
print(out)

#          John      Mike  Alan
# 0    0.010539  0.013201   1.0
# 1    0.011800  0.014756   1.0
# 2    0.013201  0.016477   1.0
# 3    0.014756  1.000000   1.0
# 4    0.016477  1.000000   1.0
# ..        ...       ...   ...
# 96   1.000000  1.000000   1.0
# 97   1.000000  1.000000   1.0
# 98   1.000000  1.000000   1.0
# 99   1.000000  1.000000   1.0
# 100  1.000000  1.000000   1.0
# 
# [101 rows x 3 columns]
```

Note that the hin edges need to be one larger than the labels, because technically, this is interpreted as `(59, 60], (60, 61], ...`, i.e. including the right edge.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one! Quick question though: what if the probabilities are not unique? I've tried replacing the last probability with the second to last and this gives the error `Categorical categories must be unique` from `pd.cut`.

Comment: @JRChapman In that case you will have to pass `labels=False` (or `None`, not quite sure atm) and use the resulting indices to index into `pd.Series(death_prob)`. See also the first revision of my answer for that.

Comment: @JRChapman: It is `False`, and here is the direct link to that revision: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/245225/1